# Display login page before submitting the comment in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to display the login page before submitting the comment. When the user is not logged in and when he clicks on submit button it has to redirect to login page.. when the user is logged in the comment has to be posted. Here is the code.. Before user can comment if he is not logged in  he has to redirect to login.php page.

```
<form action="" method="post">
          

 <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Name" name="name"  value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name'];  ?>" required>
                                </div>
                               <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <textarea  class="form-control" id="mes" name="mes" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post" class="texty" class="btn newspaper-btn mt-30 w-100"  style="border:1px solid black;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: What happens to the data they entered?  (when they are *redirected* to login (at time of submit)).   Looks like:  takes 10 minutes to enter details - submit - oh, you're not logged in - loses comment as it goes to login.  Looks like a good way to annoy your users.  Better to not allow them to start entering in the form unless logged in?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $_SESSION,
check the following on your comment button

```
if(!$_SESSSION['email']')
{

//display your login box 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
if (isset($_POST['post'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['name'] == false) {
       // Go to login page.
       header('location:login.php');
    } else {
     // here your comment process.
   }
}
```